# Android SQLite Cursor returning only one entry when trying to read all entries

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I am trying to read all entries from a SQLite database table. The problem is that the cursor returns with only one entry every time. I know that the table has around 30 entries already because when I try to save the entries again, I get this error for each entry:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: list.id (code 1555)                                                                    
#################################################################
Error Code : 1555 (SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)
Caused By : Abort due to constraint violation.
(UNIQUE constraint failed: list.id (code 1555))
#################################################################
```

I have seen a couple of questions here about similar problems, but none of the solutions works for me. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
public class Table
{
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "list";

    // Column names
    private static final String ID = "id";
    private static final String INDEX = "index";
    private static final String TITLE = "title";


    private static final String CREATE_STATEMENT = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME +
            "(" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + TITLE + " TEXT, " + 
              INDEX + " INTEGER)";

    public static void create(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_STATEMENT);
    }

    public static void drop(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    }

    public static void saveList(SQLiteDatabase db, ArrayList<MyObject> list)
    {
        for (MyObject obj : list)
        {
            long id = insert(db, obj);
        }
    }

    private static long insert(SQLiteDatabase db, MyObject obj)
    {
        final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ID, obj.getId());
        values.put(INDEX, obj.getIndex());
        values.put(TITLE, obj.getTitle());
        return db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }

    public static ArrayList<MyObject> loadList(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        final ArrayList<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        Log.d(TABLE_NAME, "Cursor size: " + cursor.getCount());
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                final long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ID));
                final String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TITLE));
                final int index = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(INDEX));
                list.add(new MyObject(id, index, title);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return list;
    }
}
```

I have also tried using `cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, ..., null)` but got the same results.

This is how I call the above functions from my `SQLiteOpenHelper` class:

```
public void saveList(ArrayList<MyObj> list)
{
    final SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Table.drop(db);
    Table.create(db);
    Table.saveList(db, list);
}

public ArrayList<MyObject> loadList()
{
    return Table.loadList(getReadableDatabase());
}
```

I have another table in the same database that has very similar code but works just fine. I have been trying to fix that for a while now, but I can't see what may be going on. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What does `cursor.getCount()` log?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao it returns 1 but I know there are more in the table

Comment: while inserting data to table what is you ID value for each row?

Comment: Make sure your database actually have some value. Use **[`SQLiteBrowser`](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/releases)** or any other IDE to view your table.

Comment: It all looks ok to me. You're certain you have more than one row in the DB? What does `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM"  + TABLE_NAME` return? That should give you an accurate count of the rows in the table.

Comment: it returns only 1. above he cleared this. As per his log the issue is with his unique key constraint(insert command)

Comment: can you please post your saveList array data. Or make it confirm you are not mistaking with your primaryKey

Comment: His log issue is used as evidence that the row already exists. This is normal expected behavior when you try to insert two elements with the same ID. Yes the query above shows that there is only one row in the table, but he does not believe that to be true, so the count(*) query just confirms that. Once once we confirm that there is only one row in the database, we can look at why is insert is not working. it may be an issue with duplicate keys, but the way the question is worded, It does not lead me to believe that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have issue with your

> obj.getId()

```
private static long insert(SQLiteDatabase db, MyObject obj)
{
    final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ID, obj.getId()); // check whether you are updating this with different value or not
    values.put(INDEX, obj.getIndex());
    values.put(TITLE, obj.getTitle());
    return db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}
```

Comment: I am using `new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextLong()` to generate the ID  but somehow the ID for all the 31 entries is the same. Just realized that based on your comments and answer. Thank you

Comment: your logcat is displaying the constraint issue and you did not noticed that

Comment: I thought it's because the entry was already there from a previous insert not that different entries are having the same ID

Comment: yeah, i think you are not much familiar with sql query and constraints :D

Comment: (SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)...this key is not allowing you to insert new data into your table

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem once, try adding an id field ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT )  to the table, once I added that field I was able to retrieve more rows as I wanted

Comment: adding AUTOINCREMENT to the _ID column solve the problem